# Retry the same request which has just failed due to error in RXJava with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

**Problem statement:** Whenever an error occurs for the request, I am showing snackbar in the UI which has a RETRY button on it. When clicking on retry button same request should be made. I have tried various things but no success, this is one code snippet which I have tried just now.

**In Presenter:**

```
private val _retryClickObserver: PublishSubject<Unit> = PublishSubject.create()

@VisibleForTesting
val retryClickObserver: PublishSubject<Unit> = _retryClickObserver 

fun loadData() {
        addSubscription(repository.getData()
            .doOnSubscribe { view.showProgressBar() }
            .doAfterTerminate { view.hideProgressBar() }
            .retryWhen { observable ->
                observable.zipWith(itemClickObserver.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST),
                    BiFunction<Throwable, Any, Any> { _: Throwable, Any -> Any
                    })
            }
            .subscribe({ handleResult(it) }, { handleError(it) }
            )
        )
    }
```

**In Fragment:**

```
override fun showErrorMessage() {
        showSnackBar(rootLayout, R.string.try_again) {           
                presenter.retryClickObserver.onNext(Unit)
            }

        }
    }
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Your retry never call loadData function again

Comment: @ Armel Gildas Fagbedji I did not get it, I need this call when retry button is clicked.

Comment: Your retryClickObserver function didn’t call loadData function

Comment: Armel Gildas Fagbedji No It's not rexecuting after etryWhen, I am unable to see snackbar.

Comment: Where have you call showErrorMessage function

Comment: showErrorMessage is a callback to view when error is occurred.

Comment: Have you call observeOn with main thread?